# How to get historical quarter end dates in SQL

Tags: sql

Can someone please help me with a script to fetch historical quarter end dates.

I'm basically looking for series of dates as below;

```
31/3/2013
30/6/2013
30/9/2013
31/12/2013
31/3/2014
30/6/2014
30/9/2014
31/12/2014
31/3/2015
30/6/2015
30/9/2015
31/12/2015
```

I have tried couple of scripts but I was able to get only current quarter dates. I'm not able to generate list of historical quarter end dates.

Comment: Which dbms? (Too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use SQL Server you can use this script:

```
DECLARE @DateTable TABLE (InputDate     datetime
                        , QEndDate      datetime)

DECLARE @QDate datetime = '20130101'

WHILE @QDate < GETDATE()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @DateTable
    SELECT      @QDate
                , DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, @QDate) + 1, 0))
    SET         @QDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 3, @QDate)
END

SELECT * FROM @DateTable
```